# child htaccess to override parent's

Tags: .htaccess

In my root directory I have a htaccess file which is caching all sort of file types. However in one subdirectory I would like to disable php caching. There I have setup the same htaccess file as in the root with php caching set to 0, but it does not take effect.

Now, I have looked into numerous discussions, some say parent htaccess takes precedence, while other claim child htaccess does.

It seems to me the former is true. The question is which command can I use in child's htaccess to override parent's htaccess?

Tnx

Comment: Nobody? Wov, seems it is really difficult when on stackoveflow in 3 days I don't get even a comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no answers after a fair amount of time so I'm gonna close this question. For my case I applied a workaround solution.

After caching files like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl|css|js|php)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

I have disabled caching for certain files like this:

```
<Files myfile.php>
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, must-revalidate"
</Files>
```

Maybe it will be of some use to somebody.

Comment: I am having a similar issue where my sub-folder header is not overriding the parent header.